# Single command to do "cryptsetup luksOpen" and "mount"?

Tags: linux, mount

I currently have the following script. I run this manually when I need to mount the disk described. I don't need/want this disk auto-mounted on boot:

```
disk1="/dev/disk/by-uuid/84ea2a10-abcd-abcd-abcd-06deabcdabcd"
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen "${disk1}" disk1-crypt
sudo mount /dev/mapper/disk1-crypt /mnt/disk1
```

Is it possible to set up Linux such that it knows to automatically do the luksOpen command when I try to mount this disk? If possible, also luksClose when I unmount it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an elegant solution, but it may serve your use case (and it's definitely how I would solve it myself).

You can create a bash script that overrides the `mount` command as an alias, checking the arguments and doing what you need when that exact argument is passed, falling back to the actual `mount` command when anything else is passed.

Have a look at this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mount_disk1 () {
    disk1="/dev/disk/by-uuid/84ea2a10-abcd-abcd-abcd-06deabcdabcd"
    sudo cryptsetup luksOpen "${disk1}" disk1-crypt
    sudo mount /dev/mapper/disk1-crypt /mnt/disk1
}

[[ "$@" == "disk1" ]] && mount_disk1 \
|| mount "$@"
```

Here you have a function that does what you want. If the only thing you pass into it is `disk1` it will execute that function, else it'll execute the original `mount` passing all arguments.

You can put this script in a folder and set an alias in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` using

```
alias mount='<path to script>'
```

Then if you want to use the original `mount`, you can run `\mount` in the terminal.

Hope it helps (again)!